# Pass API result after the user switched page while still waiting for respnse

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I created an Online Shop, which fetches the items sold via API when the user navigates to the landing page. The result of the API request gets stored in a useState hook and will later be passed to the "*ShopPage*" using props, where the Items get displayed.

My problem is, that if a user starts on the Landing page and there for triggers the API request but then immediately switches to the "*ShopPage*" before the API sent the response it won't load the "*ShopPage*" at all (which makes sense because there is no response to load the page with yet).

My current workaround is to just check whether the passed prop is empty, and if it is I just send another API request which works just fine. But has a bad impact on performance since I technically send two requests where only one would be needed.

Is there a way to send the API request from the landing page, then swap to the "*ShopPage*" and have the landing page send an update as soon as the response has arrived?

**App.js**

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
    fetchProductsCat(categories).then(function(result){
        try {
            console.log(result.data)
            setProducts(result.data)
        } catch {
            console.log(result)
        }
    })        
}, []);

  // Component with passed props
 <Route path='/Shop' exact render={() => (
       <Products setValue={setParentValue} 
                 allProducts={products}
                 allCategories={categories} />
  )}/>
```

**ShopPage**

```
export const Products = ({ setValue, allProducts, allCategories}) => {

    const [products, setProducts] = useState(allProducts)
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState(allCategories)

    useEffect(() => {
        setCategories(allCategories)
        setProducts(allProducts)
    },[])
```

[image: App.js HTML-Structure]

Comment: Can you explain: before the API sent the response it won't load the "ShopPage" at all (which makes sense because there is no response to load the page with yet).

Comment: So the "Shop Page" relies on the API response. The API response contains the name of the item, pictures, the price, etc. So if I don't pass that to the "ShopPage" it has nothing to load. The loading works well if I trigger the API response on the Landingpage, then wait for the response and then swap to the "ShopPage" because then the passed prop "allProducts" is not empty. But if a user switches to the "ShopPage" before the response it wont get updated.

Comment: So how can someone switch to the ShopPage when it can only be triggered from an api response

Comment: Maybe you have to unable that switching mechanism until the api has loaded

Comment: If I disable the switching it would make the website very user-unfriendly I guess. I considered that but I was rather looking for a way to send an update to the ShopPage as soon as the LandingPage got the API response.

Comment: This is possible. If they are linked by a child-parent relation.

Comment: That's what i thought, but how do you link them, they don't really have a relation because they are two separate pages, but they are siblings in the App.js (screenshot).